# Is there a way to stop the touches method after something has happened?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

Working on an IOS game and I want the touches to essentially not work after the player has hit a piece of debris.

This is the code for when the player hits debris:

```
-(void)dieFrom:(SKNode*)killingDebris {
    _dead = YES;

    [_player runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
                [SKAction repeatAction:[SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI duration:0] count:1],
                [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-700 duration:1],
                [SKAction runBlock:^{
        [_player removeFromParent];
    }]

    ]]];

}
```

Which works how I want it to. The issue is that the player moves based on `touchesMoved`, so if the user has their finger on the player, it stops the `moveByX` action temporarily, making the player stutter around the screen, then remove itself, which obviously looks horrible. This is the touches method:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];


}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    [_player runAction:[SKAction moveTo:[[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self] duration:0.15]];

}
```

I tried adding the following at the end of the `touchesMoved` method:

```
if (_dead == YES) {
    [self removeAllActions];         
}
```

Which didn't work either. Is there anyway I could cancel any touches when the player has hit the debris?

Comment: try [self.view endEditing:YES]; or [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

Comment: Use a boolean and do `if(ended)return;` or, `if(ended){[self touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];}` in `touchesBegan`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable touch for all the view do this;

```
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

If you want to disable touch for a specific view do this

```
yourView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

You can enable it by setting the values to YES.

Comment: This was good info, but unfortunately it didn't stop the touches if the user was already touching the screen when _dead was converted from no to yes hmmmm @Rashad

Comment: How do determine if the user is dead or alive? I mean where are you changing _dead to YES?

Comment: When there is contact between the debris and player,  so if debris hit player, _dead == YES, then to run code

Comment: @LiamStockhomme Try to disable touch after _dead = YES;

Comment: I rated your question up for your help. Unfortunately nothing is working, I'll work on it tomorrow. Thanks anyways @Rashad.